# BeautifulSoup lxml parser truncating file

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm using BeautifulSoup with python 3.4 to parse out an xml file. My code is as follows:

```
from lxml import etree
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import psycopg2
import sys
import configparser
import re

with open(informationFileName) as infoFP:
        infoTableSoup = BeautifulSoup(infoFP, "xml")

infoTableSoupFileName.write(infoTableSoup.prettify())
```

informationFileName contains the following line of text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?><informationTable xmlns:ns1="http://www.sec.gov/edgar/common" xmlns:ns11="http://www.sec.gov/edgar/statecodes" xmlns="http://www.sec.gov/edgar/document/thirteenf/informationtable" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sec.gov/edgar/common eis_Common.xsd http://www.sec.gov/edgar/statecodes eis_stateCodes.xsd http://www.sec.gov/edgar/document/thirteenf/informationtable eis_13FDocument.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><infoTable><nameOfIssuer>1ST SOURCE CORP</nameOfIssuer><titleOfClass>COM</titleOfClass><cusip>336901103</cusip><value>166</value><shrsOrPrnAmt><sshPrnamt>3364</sshPrnamt><sshPrnamtType>SH</sshPrnamtType></shrsOrPrnAmt><investmentDiscretion>SOLE</investmentDiscretion><otherManager>1</otherManager><votingAuthority><Sole>3364</Sole><Shared>0</Shared><None>0</None></votingAuthority></infoTable></informationTable>
</XML>
</TEXT>
</DOCUMENT>
</SEC-DOCUMENT>
```

The text is unfortunately all on one line. When I run this program, the prettified xml is truncated as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<informationTable xmlns:ns1="htt"/>
```

However, if I format the xml before running to the below, then it is prettified correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?><informationTable xmlns:ns1="http://www.sec.gov/edgar/common" xmlns:ns11="http://www.sec.gov/edgar/statecodes" xmlns="http://www.sec.gov/edgar/document/thirteenf/informationtable" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sec.gov/edgar/common eis_Common.xsd http://www.sec.gov/edgar/statecodes eis_stateCodes.xsd http://www.sec.gov/edgar/document/thirteenf/informationtable eis_13FDocument.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <infoTable>
        <nameOfIssuer>1ST SOURCE CORP</nameOfIssuer>
        <titleOfClass>COM</titleOfClass>
        <cusip>336901103</cusip>
        <value>166</value>
        <shrsOrPrnAmt>
            <sshPrnamt>3364</sshPrnamt>
            <sshPrnamtType>SH</sshPrnamtType>
        </shrsOrPrnAmt>
        <investmentDiscretion>SOLE</investmentDiscretion>
        <otherManager>1</otherManager>
        <votingAuthority>
            <Sole>3364</Sole>
            <Shared>0</Shared>
            <None>0</None>
        </votingAuthority>
    </infoTable>
</informationTable> 
</XML> </TEXT> </DOCUMENT> </SEC-DOCUMENT>
```

Why is this the case? I'm not doing anything except adding some newlines. I thought that BeautifulSoup wasn't supposed to care about the formatting of the file.

Comment: Your Python code contains nothing that prints or shows the parsing result. Please [edit] it and add the code that you use and that generates the truncated output.

Comment: It's an invalid xml instance, this is wrong `</XML> </TEXT> </DOCUMENT> </SEC-DOCUMENT>` there's no such opening tags in it,

Comment: @mluis7 Even if I take out the `</XML> </TEXT> </DOCUMENT> </SEC-DOCUMENT>`, it still doesn't work. That was one of the first things I tried.